# How do I insert new columns into a .csv file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, columns

Example Data:

```
"Monday","12345","Friday"
```

In the above file, I want to add a new column in between 12345 and Friday.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is your goal achieving this using awk or is it simply inserting a new column? If the latter, then the easiest way would be to use a spreadsheet application like LibreOffice Calc - it can import and export CSV files.

Answer (score 9):

To do not involve some heavy instruments (like `sed` or `awk`):

```
paste -d',' <(cut -d',' -f-2 file) column.file <(cut -d',' -f3- file)
```

This assumes that the column you want to add is saved in the file `column.file`.

Comment: Neat trick! Never heard of paste...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is as simple as you show, you could do

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{k=$3; $3="\"new text\""; $4=k}1' file
```

Or,

```
perl -F, -lane 's/$F[1]/$F[1],"new text"/; print' file
```

However, this will fail with data that can contain nested commas like:

```
"foo", "bar,baz", "bar"
```

The above is a valid csv file but these solutions will treat it as having 4 fields, not 3. If your data can contain cases like that, you should use a proper csv parser instead.

Comment: In case that all lines in new column is same and == "new text" but in most cases it is not true. If new column is stored in `column.file` : `awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$(NF+1)=$NF; getline $(NF-1) < "column.file"}1' file`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but the cut/paste answer didn't quite work for me as I wanted a blank field, so this worked for me:

1. Find out how many lines you have in the file you are inserting:

   ```
   wc -l file.csv
   ```
2. so let's say `1.` gave you 30 then use a bash loop to insert a null field between fields 3 & 4:

   ```
   paste -d, <(cut -d, -f-3 file.csv) <(for i in `seq 1 30`; do echo; done) <(cut -d, -f4- file.csv) > fileNew.csv
   ```